# Computational cost of applicative style

Tags: haskell, applicative

I am using a small database pool in my web app. And this particular function:

```
withPool pool = bracket (takeConn pool) (putConn pool)
```

can be rewritten in applicative style:

```
withPool = bracket <$> takeConn <*> putConn
```

Arguably it is just as readable and much more elegant. So naturally, I want to write it like that. But database connection pool supposed to be fast, and I am afraid that this style introduces unnecessary overhead.

So my question is, how much overhead (if any) does use of applicative functors incur in Haskell? Are there any benchmarks?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I really suspect they'll be compiled down to the same thing in most cases.
I did a tiny test,

```
import Control.Applicative

test1 :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
test1 bracket takeConn putConn pool = bracket (takeConn pool) (putConn pool)

test2 :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
test2 bracket takeConn putConn = bracket <$> takeConn <*> putConn
```

but I am constraining the type of test2 there to only functions (which isn't its most generalised type, right..?)

Then I compiled with `ghc -O -ddump-simpl` to get some sort of intermediate output from GHC (I tried the C output, it was too ugly) and the two came out looking exactly the same, except for names.

(I also tried without -O though, and they weren't the same, nor if I leave out the type annotations)

Comment: Almost any of the high performance functions are specialized and have rules to auto-convert such a less effective function into a more effective One.

Answer (score 12):

If you're worried about that level of micro-optimisation, you should be hand-rolling assembly.

Write clear and elegant code first and foremost. If speed is an issue, do some profiling and optimise the hot-spots.

Given how simple the definition of Monad ((->) r) is, you really should trust GHC to inline the definitions for you, at which point the two versions become identical up to alpha-renaming.