# Which applicative functor is used for passing shared parameters?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I think I kind of understand how applicative functors work in Haskell and I'm using them for basic datatypes (Maybe, Either...). However, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230043/computational-cost-of-applicative-style) with the following example:

```
withPool pool = bracket (takeConn pool) (putConn pool)
```

can be rewritten in applicative style:

```
withPool = bracket <$> takeConn <*> putConn
```

I was surprised it compiled and indeed it works as expected, but could somebody tell me which Applicative Functor is used for this and how is it defined?

Update: I think I figured out how it works, but I have no idea where is it defined.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unify `f` = `(a ->)` in the type signatures:

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
pure :: b -> (a -> b)
(<*>) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

The only reason the declarations are syntactically different, `((->) a)` vs `(a ->)`, is that you aren't allowed to take sections at the type level.  So you end up with these, after chasing types:

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap = (.)

instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    f <*> g = \x -> f x $ g x
```

I'm pretty sure the `Functor` instance is in `Data.Functor`, and the `Applicative` instance is in `Control.Applicative`.  The `Monad` instance for `((->) a)` is the only one in a strange spot, in `Control.Monad.Instances`, instead of `Control.Monad`.  At least if I recall correctly.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is in fact the reader monad, minus a `newtype` wrapper--the "shared parameter" here is the same as the "environment" for `Reader`. In a similar way, `Either err` is the the error monad and `(,) w` is writer.

Comment: @C.A.McCann It's worth pointing out, and I forgot to. Thanks for adding that.